# Why need std::minmax_element?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

Why do we need a combo version of `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` for `std::minmax_element`? Is it just for saving comparisons, or other benefits behind it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::min_element` and `std::max_element` need to traverse the entire container before they return. If you use `std::min_element` followed by `std::max_element` then that's two traversals, whereas if you use `std::minmax_element` then you only need one.

So yes, it's "just" for saving comparisons, but I think halving the amount of work you need to do to retrieve needed data with no loss of clarity is very worthwhile.

Comment: Note also that `std::minmax_element` finds _last_ biggest element while `std::max_element` finds _first_ biggest element. [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Comment: Yeah. O(n) is a bit of expensive. Saving one traversal looks worth.

Comment: Writing the complexity as `O(n)` (i.e. `n` with whatever irrelevant constant factor) is a bit strange when you are going to argue constant factors... You meant `ϴ` by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Check a [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

It lists the **two differences** :

> This algorithm is different from `std::make_pair(std::min_element(), std::max_element())`, not only in efficiency, but also in that this algorithm finds the *last* biggest element while `std::max_element` finds the *first* biggest element.

The mentioned efficiency gain, is because `std::minmax_element` only requires to process the data once, whereas running both `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` would require processing the data twice.

Comment: It isn't just processing the data once, it can also perform fewer comparisons in total this way (3n/2 instead of 2n). Which by the way makes it slower than calling min_element and max_element in some cases (for instance an array of int or double in random order on x86, because of worse branch prediction).